# How to show annotations on the upper half og mapview?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a special case that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I have a full screen mapview as a background. Of the lower half I have som other elements and I need to set the mapregion for my mapview, so that all annotations is visible and positioned in the upper half of the view.

[image]

I can find the maprect for all annotations.
I can also find the rect for the upper half - even translate that into a maprect.

But how do I correlate these two maprects in order to move (and squeeze) the maprect-that-fits the annotations, into the upper half?

Can anybody give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a rather simple but efficient solution for this.

The idea is to use a map rect instead of a region.

```
MKMapRect totalMapRect = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
    {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        totalMapRect = MKMapRectUnion(totalMapRect, mapRect);
    }
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:totalMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 30, 30 + verticalOffset, 30) animated:YES];
```

The idea is to iterate over all annotations and create a minimal map rect for each and union them together. This will give you the minimal rect for all annotations.

Then you can use the `[setVisibleMapRect: edgePadding:]` and add any margin so that pins will be in screen and the lower margin should just be the margin + offset.

This works for multiple annotations, but for 1 annotation the rect will be so narrow that the map will be zoomed too much to make sense.
In this case you'll have to fiddle around with the rect size.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar design once, except it was for a single annotation and not multiple but in principle its the same thing.

In ViewDidLayoutSubviews:

1. Make a MKRegion that contains your annotation(s) Create a CGPoint
   that is at the center of part of the map that is not covered.
2. Change
   the center of your region to the center of the uncovered map portion
   by using MKMapView.convert(point: toCoordinateFrom:)
3. Show the new
   center by calling mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

You need to figure out what region contains your annotations (not hard just find max and min lat, lon and add padding).  Here is example code for the rest of it:

```
        let point = CGPoint(x: mapView.bounds.size.width/2, y: -100)
        region.center = mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
```

Comment: I was unsure if how to project the center correctly, but it seems like I overthought it. I found a rather simple solution where I don't need to thing about regions and projecting the center. See my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative solution (Swift 4.2)**

[Josh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012441/josh-homann) solution works, but it requires you to set the region twice which might look like lag in your application, so I'd recommend against it. Instead, you can shift your region that fits your annotation(s) up in advance using some simple coordinate know-how and then you only need to set the map's region once.

The `MKCoordinateRegion`'s span attribute has all the info you need to make the shift. The span represents the amount of degrees that can be traveled across your map's view ie. a span with a `latitudeDelta` of one means the distance from the top of the map to the bottom is one latitudinal degree. So simply shift your region's center coordinate up by a shift based on the span:

```
var coordinate = regionThatFitsYourAnnotation.center
let span = regionThatFitsYourAnnotation.span
coordinate.latitude = coordinate.latitude - (span.latitudeDelta * 1/5) // 1/5 works well for my needs, adjust to your liking.
let shiftedRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
mapView.setRegion(shiftedRegion, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good amount of time playing around with the above answers and couldn't get a functional solution.

Heres a solution I got working that will let you zoom to an offset equivalent to a % of the mapview.

https://gist.github.com/BrentMifsud/2b8ced4789e2c50e5269b1af60aa1717

So if you wanted a set of annotation to show up 25% away from the top of the map view, you would use offset 0.25. or -0.25 if you want it to show up at the bottom half.

it works automatically for landscape as well. So if your phone is in landscape orientation, the 0.25 offset will zoom the annotations to the right side of the screen. and -0.25 will zoom them to the left half of the screen.